# Using for loop to include pdf files to latex

Tags: pdfpages, loops

I want to generate a template which accepts n as a variable and then includes the pdf files in directory DIR1, ..., DIRN.

Something like this

```
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {1,...,n} {
    \includepdf[pages=1,link,linkname=FILE**x**,scale=0.90,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{includepdfpage}\label{FILE**x**.\theincludepdfpage}\chapter{File **x**}{}}]{../Ex/File_Signed.pdf}

}
```

Is something like this feasible in latex?

Comment: Do you mean *all* PDF files in the various directories?

Comment: Yes. Exactly....

Comment: tHE SAME PROBLEM EXPLAINED HERE. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25105/unable-to-link-to-inserted-pages-with-pdfpages